# Manipulating value from complex query in Neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j DB and I have a Neo4j DB with the following nodes,

1. Attribute
2. Entity1
3. Entity2 - has relation with children as label CHILD

   1. Entity2-1
   2. Entity2-2
      ...
   3. Entity2-n

And all entities may have relation with others which has label `VALUE` and property value.

Relationships:

1. `Entity2` -> `Attribute`
2. `Entity2-n` -> `Attribute`
3. `Entity2` -> `Entity1`
4. `Entity2-n` -> `Entity1`
5. `Entity1` -> `Attribute`

I need to fetch these node's relation values and if entity has no direct value then need to fetch it's parent entity value.

For example, if `entity2-2`has no relation with `Attribute`, then need to check if it's parent `entity2` has relation with value, if not get the `Attribute` node value.

For this, I am trying this query, but not working as expected and getting empty values

```
MATCH (a:ATTRIBUTE {name: 'test' })
match (e1:ENTITY1 {id:'c0f333ca-a9cc-4c09-ac30-7c460512f1f9' })
optional match ((e1)-[entity1GlobalValue:VALUE {id:a.id}]->(a)) 

optional match ((e2:ENTITY2 {id: 'c47004cc-3f48-51fd-9a38-69274341e344'})-[:CHILD]->(e2Children:ENTITY2))
optional match ((e2Children)<-[:CHILD*]-(e2Parent:ENTITY2))

optional match ((e2Children)<-[e2ChildrenE1Values:VALUE {id:a.id}]-(e1))
optional match ((e2Parent)<-[e2ParentE1Values:VALUE {id:a.id}]-(e1))

optional match ((e2Children)<-[e2ChildrenGlobalValues:VALUE {id:a.id}]-(a))
optional match ((e2Parent)<-[e2ParentGlobalValues:VALUE {id:a.id}]-(a))

RETURN a, e1, entity1GlobalValue, e2Children, e2ChildrenE1Values, e2ParentE1Values, e2ChildrenGlobalValues, e2ParentGlobalValues;
```

1. Not sure what is the mistake here?
2. Is my query effiecent ? There is Unique constraint on `id` field.

**Update:**

Rough diagram:

Here I am looking for value which is stored in the relations between Nodes.
`Entity2` has children `Entity2-1` and `Entity2-2`, where I have to find the value for these children with other entities - `Entity1` and `Attribute`.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Using optional match looks good. please give us example scripts to create the data similar to this: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node-similarity/#algorithms-node-similarity-examples

Comment: It might make sense to use https://arrows.app to draw an example of the graph and what you _want_ to return from the query

Comment: @CharlotteSkardon - added the diagram with example graph. I need to get value which is stored in between nodes as relations(:VALUE). For example, if there is no relation between, `Entity2-1` and `Entity1`, then check for relation between `Entity2` and `Entity1`, if not check between `Entity1` and `Attribute` and still there is no relation check for relation between `Entity2-1` and `Attribute`... so on..

Comment: @jose_bacoy - I have added a rough graph diagram. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the graph provided I understand that you have to get the values for the child nodes which has relationship VALUE. If that's the case find the below query.

```
MATCH (n:Entity2)-[:CHILD]->(c) 
with collect(c)+n as childNodes 
UNWIND childNodes as cNode 
MATCH (cNode)-[v:VALUE]->(endNode) 
RETURN 
    labels(cNode) as fromNode,
    v.value as value, 
    labels(endNode) as toNode
```

The result would be
[image]

What I have done is assuming the starting Node as parent Node I have collected all the child nodes plus the parentNode and using unwind looping each node collected and checking whether it has VALUE relationship and if so returning the values.

Hope this helps!

If not let me know what's the result you are expecting.

Thanks!